# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range when trying to check if a word is a palindrome

Tags: java, string

I been trying write code that checks  if a word is a word that the first letter and the last letter are the same. In essence, it's code that checks to see if a Word is a palindrome.

#### Code

```
import java.util.*;

public class Class1 {
   static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String n = reader.next();
       boolean right = true;
       for (int i=0; i<n.length();i++)
       {
           int f = n.length()-i;
           if (n.charAt(i) != n.charAt(f -i))
           {
               right=false;
           }
        
       }
       System.out.println("The word is " + right);
   }    
}
```

I get this error:

```
TT
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at Class1.main(Class1.java:12)
```

Thank you.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. What don't you understand? Ask yourself this question: if a string has N characters, and the index of the first one is 0, what is the index of the last one?

Comment: In English this is called a Palindrome. You can [search for examples on Google](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=stackoverflow%20java%20pallindrome&safe=off).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost right, just `int f = n.length()-i;` should be `int f = n.length()-1;`.

`n.length()-1` is the index of the last character in the string. So `f-i` will be the *i*-th character from the right.

Comment: Well @JBNizet already answered my question in a comment section of other answer, but I cant give him this V and your answer is just as helpfull, so thank you too :D

Answer (score 0):

Suppose take an example the length of String is `3` and when i reaches `2` then according to you `f` will be 1

then take this line `n.charAt(f -i)` it will be like `charAt(1-2)` so definately it will throw some exception

Try something like this

```
    int s = n.length();
    for (int i=0; i<(s/2)+1;++i) {
        if (n.charAt(i) != n.charAt(s - i - 1)){
            right=false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The word is " + right);
```

Dont forget to debug the code to know about the flow only finding the solution is never going to help you

Comment: Can I have a little bit of help with that? as I think you said (sorry, very bad english, and google translate is not perfect..) that f goes each time 1 down until it reaches -1 and thats the exception, how can I fix that without ruining my code?

Comment: @TOMER: that's one of the problems, but not the first one. Ask yourself this question: if a string has N characters, and the index of the first one is 0, what is the index of the last one? Once you have the answer, check what `n.charAt(f -i)` does when `i = 0`.

Comment: @SparkOn, n.length won't change (because n isn't modified) inside the for loop, so f will remain constant for the duration of the for loop. EDIT: Never mind, I saw "int f = n.length()-i;" as "int f = n.length()-1;", which is **should** be.

Comment: @JBNizet did u try executing it

Comment: @TDHofstetter then what this `--f;` is doing then?

Comment: Sorry. It works fine for abc. But it says abca is a palindrome. Hint: there is no need to continue looping once right becomes false. And there is also no need to go further than length / 2.

Comment: @JBNizet yes it is failing looking at it

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you :D it helped and now the code works!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is an index out of range, stating your input parameter for n.charAt(#) is outside n's index range, it being from 0 to n.length()-1

The error in your code however is at this point of the code:

```
int f = n.length()-i; //negate i from the length
if (n.charAt(i) != n.charAt(f -i))  //negate i from the already negated length
```

and the fix should be:

```
int f = n.length()-i-1;
if (n.charAt(i) != n.charAt(f))
```

Comment: No, that won't fix it. Ask yourself this question: if a string has N characters, and the index of the first one is 0, what is the index of the last one?

Comment: what will happen when `i=0`?

Comment: Sorry yes the index range is from 0 to n.length()-1
My mistake, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Class1 {
   static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String n = reader.next();
       boolean right = true;
       int f = n.length()-1;
       for (int i=0; i<n.length();i++)
       {
           if (n.charAt(i) != n.charAt(f-i))
           {
               right=false;
           }
       }
       System.out.println("The word is " + right);
   }    
}
```

Comment: Come on guys. It's a simple problem that the OP should figure out by himself. Couldn't you tech the man to fish instead of giving him a fish? You're not even explaing what is wrong in his code.

Comment: @JBNizet, I have a feeling that fishing instructions are going to be pretty challenging across the OP's admitted language barrier.

Answer (score 0):

To add with other answers you don't need to loop through the whole string. you only need to loop through half of the string length to see if your string is a palindrome or not.

Suppose you are checking if **madam** is palindrome or not. You have to loop half of the length of madam that is 5/2 or 2 times only.

index0 m == m index4

index1 a == a index2

So here is the slightly modified code

```
for(int i = 0;i<n.length()/2;i++) {
    if(n.charAt(i) != n.charAt(n.length()-1-i))
    {
        right=false;
    }
}
```